# Regexp: replace character

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace a character but nothing happens.

```
   const str = '//id//user/param//test';
    const result = str.replace(/[//]/gi, '/');
```

This is what i get :

```
//id//user/param//test
```

This is what i want :

```
/id/user/param/test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[...]` denotes a character group, which matches any *one* of these characters. So, `[//]` essentially means "match `/` or `/`". Thus `[//]` is the same as `[/]`.

You don't want a character group:

```js
const str = '//id//user/param//test';
console.log(str.replace(/\/\//gi, '/'));
```

If you want to match two or more `/`, use the `+` or `{2,}` quantifiers:

```
/\/{2,}/
/\/\/+/
```

Comment: now i see, because at first i was actually working withe a charcter group and i taugh it would do the same job. thank you, it worked for me now

Comment: `gi` could be simply `g`, there's nothing *insensitive*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Sure, just copied what the OP had.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it also using a regex group `/\/+/`

```js
const str = '//id//user/param//test';
const result = str.replace(/\/+/g, '/')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why the `()` in `/(\/)+/g`? You could `/\/+/g`

Comment: Yes, but why would you need a group? FWIS you just want to replace multiple instances of `/` with a single one